# Is there a way to place Angular JS form validation within a controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am currently creating a basic form for a login. I have established all of the necessary validation, but I do NOT want my HTML to be ridiculously fat. This has led me to wanting to add the validation to a controller. For example, I want to add a span with ng-bind='span' to only show if input with ng-bind='input' is invalid. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It generally is a good practice to keep your controller thin, i suggest you implement directive for validation as validation logic on controller is not reusable at all.

Comment: Also .. angulars adds classes which you can use for showing and hiding error message in such manner - `input.ng-invalid + span.error { display: inline; }`